# Help needed to reword a question so it can be re-opened

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I posted this question:

https://superuser.com/q/310549/86676

There were a couple of comments... one of them suggested I should try asking the question on Server Fault, but I don't understand this as my question is not a fault. I thought it would be very much on topic for super user. Does anybody know why this is off topic for super user?

The other comment was useful, and I took the advice and edited my question to include a load of extra information and context.

Now that I have done this, is there any reason why this cannot be reopened? And if so, what more can I add to the question to make it better?

Comment: I agree that this belongs on Server Fault. But I don't think it needs to be rewritten, there is enough information to give reasonable advice.

Answer (score 3):

As I had mentioned - your question is more suitable for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

From the [faq](https://serverfault.com/faq)

> Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support
>   professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a
>   professional capacity. If your question is about …
>
> - Servers
> - Networks
> - Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace

So, the name Server Fault is not to be taken literally. Since you don't have > 250 rep, you cannot vote to reopen it. However, you can either:

- Flag for reopen
- Post a meta question ( and you've done that!)

Comment: How do I get it moved to Server Fault? or do I just re-ask the question?

Comment: @BG100 - don't reask, we'll get it migrated shortly.

Comment: Looking at the Superuser FAQ, this question is equally on topic here: Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about: computer hardware

Comment: @BG100 SF is a better target because the target audience over there is experienced in matters such as the one mentioned in your question.

Comment: @BG100 - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room

Comment: I agree that this belongs on Server Fault. But I don't think it needs to be rewritten, there is enough information to give reasonable advice. (I manage tomcat servers for a living)